Sample size daily traffic volumes
What sample size is needed to assess daily traffic intersection volumes, to give a realistic picture for the following year

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

First, it depends on what you mean by "realistic": a simple forecast is usually quite easy to make. More data can make this more precise. But there is a limit to forecastability.
Second, it depends on your data generating process. There may or may not be multiple-seasonalities involved, which of course require more data to capture accurately.
Third, collecting predictor data may be much more helpful than just collecting a longer time series of the raw traffic data. With the Olympics going on in Paris, I imagine that some parts of town see a very different picture than normal there. Without knowing about this special event, you would not be able to forecast that well. See some more examples at How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?
Finally, you seem to be doing forecasting. You might want to take a look at the textbooks and other resources we collect at Resources/books for project on forecasting models.
